# Google play services leaderboards not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-play-services

I have a problem implementing the Google Play Services. The user login works, the `Social.ReportScore` also works, **the problem is**, displaying the leaderboards UI doesn't work.

Here is my method which I call on a button press :

```
((PlayGamesPlatform) Social.Active).ShowLeaderboardUI (myString);
```

Any idea how to fix ?

Comment: What's the error? Can you post some code?

Comment: Sure, here is my GooglePlay Manager : https://hastebin.com/etimiwivuz.cs
As you can see, I put some texts to debug the success of logging in / reporting the score, and both of those work.
I have the ShowLeaderboardsUI() called in a public method which is attached to a button, so when the button is pressed, the leaderboard should appear, but nothing happens.

Comment: I don't see a "myString" defined, are you passing a valid id?

Comment: Did you define the leaderboard properly in the google console?

Comment: MustSeeMelons - yeah, actually there I have my string but I modified on hastebin for reasons :P.
@BasilePerrenoud I think so, it wasn't nothing special which I should have done, is it ?

Comment: Once it is defined in google console, you need to export the resource and set it up in unity. Have you done that?

Comment: @BasilePerrenoud Yep, still doesn't work